# R: Forecasting Future Values of Time Series

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, forecasting

I am working with the R programming language. In particular, I am using "Markov Switching Models" for the purpose modelling more complicated dataset with varying degrees of volatility. For this problem, I am using the "MSwM" package in R:

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MSwM/MSwM.pdf
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MSwM/vignettes/examples.pdf

I am following the first example from the "vignettes":

```
#load library
library(MSwM)

#load data
data(example)

#plot data
plot(ts(example))
```

[image]

```
#fit basic model
mod=lm(y~x,example)

#fit markov switching model:

mod.mswm=msmFit(mod,k=2,p=1,sw=c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE),control=list(parallel=FALSE))
```

The above code successfully creates the model - 2 "Regimes" have been identified:

[image]

**Question:** I checked the documentation of this package, and there does not seem to be any functions that allow you to **predict** future values of this time series. I did some research and it seems like the "Markov Switching Model" should allow you to predict future values of a time series, e.g. : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90448/how-to-forecast-a-markov-switching-model

OR:

[image]

However, there does not seem to be a straightforward way to do this in R. Can someone please suggest how to resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you want `fMarkovSwitching` pkg for estimation, simulation, and forecasting?

Comment: @ Chris : Thank you for your reply! Have you used the "fMarkovSwitching" R package? Do you find that it allows for similar modelling options as does the "MSwM" package? Thanks so much!