# Forecasting Markov-Switching Autoregressive Models in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, hidden-markov-models

I recently came across the book "Nonlinear Time Series Analysis" by Tsay and Chen. I have been trying to forecast time series with markov-switching autoregressive models in R using the [MSwM package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MSwM/MSwM.pdf). Unfortunately, the package does not seem to include any functions or methods for forecasting, so I tried to reproduce the simulation approach proposed by Tsay and Chen (Section 2.3.5, page 75 f.):

[Prediction of Markov-Switching Models via Simulation (Tsay & Cheng)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0lRK.png)

To provide an example for my reproduction, consider this data set and model:

```
library(MSwM)
msw_data <- data.frame(y = c(-1.329229676, -1.162251375, -1.005434724, -1.039368100, -1.327330438, -1.724500394, -1.360861136, -1.830719671, -1.737927878, -1.415735105, -1.008930264, -1.330007547, -1.216736254, -1.170308845, -1.334933973, -1.072308279,      0.143299471, -0.923261588, -0.343721417, -0.788357005, -1.543190659, -0.760634458, -0.804952129, -1.114146766, -0.764977459, -0.825424227, -0.722213263, -1.077210632, -1.334065875, -1.595469365, -0.925889473, -0.621230275, -0.686381063,  0.394775915, -1.462414107, -1.405274279, -1.186628977, -1.057185385,  0.540352993,  0.583502480, -0.366048186, -0.806560169, -0.925256385, -0.440475656, -1.492910078, -1.238488838, -1.530738562, -1.415979685, -1.318426912, -0.800082754, -0.795133823, -1.252246337, -1.063021931, -0.959451987,  0.887210939, 3.368952379, -0.935079653, -0.802594386, -1.220124772, -1.021547827, -0.855101919, -1.069235352, -1.005650352, -1.035304558, -0.892210250, -0.804588477, -0.669207068, -0.643674721, -0.690814459, -0.695840128, -0.514718379, -0.777536927, -0.833882126, -1.066878536, -0.688785655, -0.578108163, -0.652885361, -0.429725407, -0.757509030, -0.580235056, -0.827588510, -1.268630651, -1.006496642, -0.590989043, -0.377163085, -0.631230276, -0.693207074, -0.936256554, -0.880238702, -0.749636323, -0.512768133, -0.181542825, -0.518931708, -0.296874976, -0.703917346, -0.438759099, -0.513506086, -0.540732217,  6.112027935,  6.515595664, 5.879223739,  4.103063009,  7.453652021,  2.082232874,  0.054773334, -0.122976207, -0.178034032, -0.293548223, -0.172111275,  0.078918630, 0.333712104,  0.086438704,  0.146498030,  0.497359230,  0.147085616, 0.351515209,  0.260850638,  0.163510458,  0.134405966,  0.646249202, 0.286313761,  0.419255790,  0.653625321,  0.418075656,  5.599469700, 1.632364822,  2.431602576,  5.413993384,  7.955155458,  3.937311435, 0.106253070, -0.423219642, -1.314772518, -1.094392731, -1.345704356, -1.252268585, -1.790410765, -1.682718888, -1.523734359, -2.011173481, -1.791449740, -1.474951721, -1.751749916, -1.551362210, -1.405103423, -1.516826255, -1.184083723, -0.953966792, -0.828391478, -0.716280911, -0.695619285, -0.305139496, -0.285052675,  0.147269792,  0.008212979, 0.274672100,  0.667992590,  0.518312153,  0.481037813,  0.480127453, 0.753790625,  0.696163516,  0.725199781,  1.014005724,  0.950449472, 1.050455657,  1.216981775,  1.395107210,  1.404440629,  1.383076706, 1.286466152,  1.313333369,  1.524647563,  1.823361953,  1.854311335, 2.071432268,  2.117567924,  2.235024944,  2.190946649,  2.239725827, 2.026836517,  1.767428864,  1.735376945,  1.712400198,  1.651565453, 1.744513659,  1.687920757))

# Markov-Switching Model with AR(1)
msw_base <- lm(y ~ 1, data = msw_data)
msw_model <- msmFit(msw_base, k=2, sw=rep(TRUE,3), p = 1)
```

With this preliminaries, my reproduction would look like this:

```
library(markovchain)
ms_states <- paste("Regime", seq(1, msw_model@k, by = 1))
ms_matrix <- new("markovchain", states = ms_states,
                 transitionMatrix = matrix(msw_model@transMat,
                                           nrow = nrow(msw_model@transMat), byrow = TRUE,
                                           dimnames = list(ms_states, ms_states)))
# In which regime is the last observed time series value located?
ms_regime <- paste("Regime", which(msw_model@Fit@filtProb[nrow(msw_model@Fit@filtProb),] > 100/msw_model@k/100))

# Object to store my 1'000 simulation paths, each runnig 75 iterations
msw_forec <- matrix(NA, nrow=75, ncol=1e+3)

# Simulation Procedure
for(k in 1:1e+3){
  # Last value of the observed time series
  start_value <- msw_data$y[length(msw_data$y)]
  # Generating markov chain sequence for simulation iteration, transform from character to number
  state_chain <- as.numeric(
    gsub("Regime ", "", 
         markovchainSequence(n = 75, markovchain = ms_matrix, t0 = ms_regime)))
  # Storage object for simulated values
  value_chain <- NULL
  # Random variates from the distribution of e_t assumed to be iid N(0,1)
  e_t <- rnorm(75,0,1)
  
  # Loop for 75 iterations along the simulation path
  for(i in 1:75){
    value_chain[i] <- msw_model@Coef[state_chain[i],1] + 
      msw_model@Coef[state_chain[i],2]*(start_value - msw_model@Coef[state_chain[i],1]) + 
      e_t[i]
    # Storing t+1, ..., t+h value as new starting value
    start_value <- value_chain[i]
  }
  # Storing simulated path in storage object
  msw_forec[,k] <- value_chain
}
```

Since I'm pretty new to R and have quite literally no experience using loops, not to mention using loops complex simulations, I'm unsure, if I've missed something.

```
# Plotting results
plot(c(msw_data$y, rep(NA, 75)), type ="l", ylim =c(-15,15))
for(i in 2:1e+3){lines(c(rep(NA, 187), msw_forec[,i]), col ="grey")}

# Point and Interval Forecasts
lines(c(rep(NA, 187), rowMeans(msw_forec)), col="red")
lines(c(rep(NA, 187), rowMeans(msw_forec) + 1.96*apply(msw_forec, 1, sd)), col="darkgreen", lty=3)
lines(c(rep(NA, 187), rowMeans(msw_forec) - 1.96*apply(msw_forec, 1, sd)), col="darkgreen", lty=3)
# Comparing MSwM model with classical AR(1) & auto.arima
library(forecast)
ar_comp <- forecast(arima(msw_data$y, order=c(1,0,0)), h=75)
lines(c(rep(NA, 187), ar_comp$mean), col="blue", lty=2)
lines(c(rep(NA, 187), ar_comp$upper[,2]), col="blue", lty=2)
lines(c(rep(NA, 187), ar_comp$lower[,2]), col="blue", lty=2)
aa_comp <- forecast(auto.arima(msw_data$y), h=75)
lines(c(rep(NA, 187), aa_comp$mean), col="purple", lty=2)
lines(c(rep(NA, 187), aa_comp$upper[,2]), col="purple", lty=2)
lines(c(rep(NA, 187), aa_comp$lower[,2]), col="purple", lty=2)
```

My simulated forecasts have quite large prediction intervals compared to non-swichting AR(1) models and models fitted with auto.arima(), and although they are not directly comparable, it makes me wonder, if my simulation is correctly implemented. Did I miss anything or would it be a more suitable approach to follow [this approach](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90448/how-to-forecast-a-markov-switching-model) for forecasting markov-switching models? Any help or feedback is highly appreciated, as I'm feeling a bit lost at the moment. Thank you!

Disclosure: A related question has been previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68877015/r-forecasting-future-values-of-time-series) without an accepted answer or code.